# Can I get an Android app to read a Windows computer registry

Tags: android, windows, registry

I've to write an Android app that takes pictures and posts the results to a Windows Server.

Before posting I have to access the registry file on the server to extract info to aid in posting the file.

Any clues as to how to approach this.

Thanks,

David.

Comment: Post it to IIS on the server and let that handle the registry logic?

Comment: Like Joachim says, you just split your logic into two requests. The first one requests the required information from the server, which queries it from the fregistry. The second request does the actual upload of the image data, using the information acquired in the first request.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, it is possible to issue remote registry commands since the [protocol is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc244877.aspx).  Probably more trouble than it's worth, though; I would listen to the other guys.